# JAXB ignoring String on marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Ok, this is kinda driving me nuts. I have this class: http://pastebin.com/agdnDhQw
And i'm trying to (un-)marshall it from/to a XML file. It does work fine, however, no matter how many String-Variables I add to the class *HazardousItem*, or what modifiers I use (XmlAccessType.FIELD, None, ..), it is not written to the XML file. And even when I read this file back in, the unmarshaller does not complain about the missing Attribute.

Weird is, that I have another String Attribute, further down the file, which works just fine:

```
        @XmlAttribute
        protected String damageSource;
```

I even tried to add a String as XmlAttribute and XmlElement to the root-element, without success. If I change the datatype to int, it works. Just "String" seems to be ignored, in some cases.
I'm using the JAXB that comes with JRE7 1.7.0_75, if that's important.

Just for reference, this is the part of my test-output file:

```
<hazardousItems>
<hazardousItem exactMatch="false">
    <damageEffect damageSource="inFire" amount="0.5"/>
```

exactMatch is there, but not unlocName. Just in the next element, *damageEffect*, the String is exported (damageSource)

Why is that?

Comment: Is your String maybe null in cases when it is not exported? Because int is primitive type and thus never null (0 by default).

Comment: I feel SOO dump right now.. Yes, that was the solution. In my FactoryClass, due massive copy&paste, I returned a new instance of _HazardousItem_ instead of the populated one. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You're welcome. It happens to me often as well, that's why it was my first guess. :) I'll add 'official' answer below, so that others can easier see it when they encounter similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Null values are not exported by default, so String attributes with null values are not written to xml.